# How to use same external object to display different related list in the same Parent Object

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, odata

I have the following requirements.

-> In the case object (this is a salesforce object) I have to create a related list of Transfer Transactions. I achieved this. And the related object is an external object which we have using OData.

-> Additionally I have to create another related list in the same case object. And this list should be a subset of the above list (transactions with recurring flag true)

My question is how can I use the same external object to create the second related list.

(This is in lightning)

Thanks
MR

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post](https://douglascayers.com/2015/11/18/salesforce-filter-related-lists-without-code/), this is what you need in your case. OOTB there's no way to create a filtered related list.

Comment: I found a way to filter the related list. From Edit Page you can Add a filter. This is a sort of work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do it as of now:

1. Write that component yourself and break the sweat
2. Install this [Enhanced Lightning Grid](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EVK8iUAH) from Salesforce Labs which does the same. I have personally loved this product and would recommend must for admins. You can add filtered related lists and its all configurable at metadata level.

Probably in future release salesforce will add this functionality by default.